# upgrade to bootstrap 3 - jquery call to modal fails (but works in v2.3)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have upgraded my test site from bootstrap version 2.3 to version 3.3.5.

When I replaced the `bootstrap.min.js` file from v2.3 to v3.3.5, one part of my jquery code does not get called with v3.3.5 of `bootstrap.min.js`, but is called in v2.3.

After a lot of time and effort, I have been able to pinpoint where the error occurs, but I am unable to understand why this error occurs with v3.3.5 (but does work with v2.3) and I am also unable to figure out how to fix this myself. My Jquery skills are not strong.

Here is the code that I have (I have put in alerts to help me identify what is not working and what is working):

```
....
$('#change_formatting_style_button').click(function() {
    alert('a');
    if (! $('#change_formatting_style_button').attr('disabled')) {
        alert('b');
        $('#preview_modal').modal();  // this line is not called in v3.3.5.
        alert('c');
    }
    alert('d');
    return false;
});
....
```

In version 2.3 of the `bootstrap.min.js`, the line `$('#preview_modal').modal();` is called, but in version 3.3.5 it is not called. I am unsure why this fails in v3.3.5.

Below is the function that is not called:

```
$('#preview_modal').on('shown', function() {
    alert('0');
    $('#preview_contents').html($('#live_preview').html());
    alert('1');

});
```

I have searched SO and Google for assistance, but I am unable to shed any light on this.

**I am hoping that someone can point out what I have done wrong and how I can fix this issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal is initialized, but isn't shown yet. Try using:

```
 $('#preview_modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I have already tried that and the function is still not called.

Comment: Inside the function that isn't called, try changing 'shown' to 'shown.bs.modal'

Comment: Charlie Harster - That code works! Fist pump! Thanks for the solution. Where is this documented, so I can read up on it?

Comment: No problem. Been there way too many times myself. [Bootstrap Modal Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)